# In Pharo, my classes should not appear in the Browser, or even in the Smalltalk global

Tags: metaprogramming, smalltalk, pharo

I don't want my new classes to appear in the system browser, moreover, i dont think they should appear in the Smalltalk global.

By default, classes appear in the browser and in the Smalltalk global. How can I change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blog post [Pharo Superpower: Create Anonymous Class](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~akuhn/blog/2009/pharo-superpower-create-anonymous-class/) explains the creation of *anonymous classes* in all details.

Answer (score 3):

But be careful about what you ask for. Debugging invisible code is not much fun.

Comment: If my tests keep ok... i do not expect debug it, but thanks for the advice, i know it could be painful!